# How can I check my SQL to ERD code without data?

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone check if I did well with this code?
The main problem that I have only ERD without data, so I cant check it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is a noobish question, I am learning to program. And this is my first ever attempt at database design with questions which I found for beginners.

ERD:

[image]

● Which is the most ordered product?

```
SELECT product_type 
FROM   (SELECT p.`product_type`, 
               Sum(o.`amount`) AS amounts 
        FROM   `fact_item` AS o 
               INNER JOIN `dim_prouct` AS p 
                       ON o.`dim_product_id` = p.`dim_product_id` 
        GROUP  BY o.`dim_product_type` 
        ORDER  BY Sum(o.`amounts`) DESC 
        LIMIT  1)
```

Which is the most ordered product?(Maybe without join?)

```
SELECT p.`dim_product_id`, 
Count(distinct order_id) 
FROM `fact_item`
    
GROUP BY `dim_product_id`
ORDER BY count(distinct order_id) desc
LIMIT 1
```

With these questions I have no idea how to write a SQL code? Any ideas?

● How long does it take for a merchant to order again?

● How would you find the cumulative number of orders a merchant places over its lifetime?

Now Im trying to create a good code for every table. I'm stuck with dim order table. Could you help me to create this one?

```
CREATE TABLE dim_order (
  order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  country VARCHAR(100),
  paid_price INT NOT NULL,
  merchandt_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  order_date DATE NOT NULL,
  order_status VARCHAR(100),
  shipping_status VARCHAR(100),
);
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I would like to use MYSQL, the main problem that I should solve it without data :)

Comment: Learn by doing! Install a dbms, create the tables and insert some data, then you can do your queries until you've found the correct answer. I'd say that's the only way to really learn SQL.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for your support. I have already installed MySQL. Now Im trying to create a good code for every table. I stacked with dim order table. Could you help me to create this one?

Comment: @jarlh 'CREATE TABLE dim_order (
 order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 country VARCHAR(100),
 paid_price INT NOT NULL,
 merchandt_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
 order_date DATE NOT NULL,
 order_status VARCHAR(100),
 shipping_status VARCHAR(100),
);'

Comment: You have a comma `,` too much after the shipping_status  column.